# Azure Storage Emulator exception: "One of the request inputs is not valid."

Tags: azure, azure-storage-emulator

I'm setting up Azure Storage Emulator but when I attempt to put a blob in to a container, I get the above exception.

I'm working with Windows Azure Storage Emulator 4.4.0.0.

I get the same error in my code (versions 4.3.0.0 and 7.0.0.0 of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage), as well as latest version of Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer (0.7.20160509.0). In code, the failing method is **CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStream(myStream source)**.

I've hooked up Fiddler proxy and compared the request to the [Azure Blob REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179451.aspx), and it looks ok to me.

Request:

```
PUT     http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/public/broker/broker_placeholderLogo.png HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Azure-Storage/7.0.0 (.NET CLR 4.0.30319.42000; Win32NT 10.0.10586.0)
x-ms-version: 2015-07-08
Content-MD5: 1/VCBZRjnuUQPBtMviZfzw==
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
x-ms-client-request-id: fec3ada1-653b-46ec-81f0-a1602baab494
x-ms-date: Wed, 25 May 2016 14:01:17 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey devstoreaccount1:60ts48q7J714f74GWTA3sbICqGvxqg2NXPWjZQH/IXA=
Host: 127.0.0.1:10000
Content-Length: 10748
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 One of the request inputs is not valid.
Content-Length: 220
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 8882fa90-80d0-4043-a997-836f645bc349
x-ms-version: 2015-07-08
Date: Wed, 25 May 2016 14:01:17 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidInput</Code><Message>One of the request inputs is not valid.
RequestId:8882fa90-80d0-4043-a997-836f645bc349
Time:2016-05-25T14:01:17.5245914Z</Message></Error>
```

The containers are being created fine, so I don't think it's a problem with authorisation. I'm running out of ideas on what might be causing this issue.

UPDATE: I've tried removing the MD5 validation, but it made no difference.

Comment: From where did you download version 4.4.0.0 of Storage Emulator? I downloaded the latest version just now and it says version 4.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to solve it by installing version 4.3.0.0. Had the same problem today and that worked perfectly

Currently, it is still possible to download version 4.3.0.0 by going to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/ (Section: Command-line tools) and downloading the standalone package of the Azure Storage Emulator.

Comment: Thank you - yes this worked!

That main link has been updated to download 4.4, but I found 4.3 in the Microsoft Azure SDK for .Net - 2.9, which can be downloaded here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=51657

Answer (score 2):

We've investigated the issue and have determined it affects a subset of customers.  We are currently testing a hot fix to address the issue; until then, please stay on 4.3.  We apologize for the inconvenience.

[UPDATE]  An updated version of 4.4 is now available which should address this issue.

Comment: Where is this updated version Keith?  I just installed the 2.9.1 SDK hoping it would fix this, and no such luck.  Glad to hear it's been looked into.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on iOS. The problem was in request's default cache policy, it silently added *If-None-Match* header. Adding `[request setCachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];` fixed the problem for me.